# IDLE does not Run Module

Tags: python

New here and very novice in Python. I have a question about Python.
At my workplace, I have some trainings with PL/SQL, where our first task was create RPN calculator. Because I'm not that good in PL/SQL and syntax of that language is strange in my opinion, I made it in Python.
Everything worked smoothly, until a time when I was asked to create function to check if string of values are RPN. Just before that, I made simple program to check if entered values match with those in dictionary, but I stopped to Run.

```
AcceptedChars = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","+","-","/","*"," "]

def checking_for_rpn():
    checking = str(input("Enter values for check: "))
    for AcceptedCharsCheck in checking:
        if not(AcceptedCharsCheck in AcceptedChars):
            print("False")
            return False
        
    print("Ok")
    return True
```

Then, I added some crazy codes from web for checking RPN and that's fricked my code.
Now, I canot run it by Run Module. Shell displays standard view when it's ready.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the IDLE? And are you running the function?

Comment: This is clearly not a [mre] because nowhere are you actually *calling* `checking_for_rpn`. We need to see the full code or else we have no idea whatsoever how to help. I will say that `str(input(whatever))` is useless because `input` always returns a `str`, but that's not going to break your program. Anyway, if this is your actual full code, then the issue is that you wrote a function that you are not calling. You have to call a function for it to be executed.

Comment: @RandomDavis nevermind, it worked. Per your suggestion, I just called function in the end of code. It works now. Thanks!